# My lambda function isn't working properly

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Im trying to make lambda compress all the images uploaded to a certain file in my bucket so here what i did :

1. I created a lambda function with prefix : myfile/*/
2. I deployed my nodejs code

```
//Import compress module
const imagemin = require('imagemin');
const imageminMozjpeg = require('imagemin-mozjpeg');
const sharp = require('sharp');

const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

const s3 = new AWS.S3()
exports.handler = async (event) =>{
    // TODO implement
    
    const srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    
    const srcKey    = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));
    const dstBucket = "safarni";
    const dstKey    =  srcKey;
    
    console.log(srcKey, dstBucket, dstKey)
     // Download the image from the S3 source bucket. 
    try {
        const params = {
            Bucket: srcBucket,
            Key: srcKey
        };
        var origimage = await s3.getObject(params).promise();

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
    }  
    console.log('here')
    const jpgBuffer = sharp(origimage.Body).toBuffer().jpeg().toBuffer()
    
    //Compressing the photo
        const compressedjpgBuffer = await imagemin.buffer(jpgBuffer, {
            plugins: [imageminMozjpeg({ quality: 85 })]
        })
        
    // Upload the thumbnail image to the destination bucket
    try {
        const destparams = {
            Bucket: dstBucket,
            Key: dstKey,
            Body: compressedjpgBuffer,
            ContentType: "image"
        };

        const putResult = await s3.putObject(destparams).promise(); 
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
    } 
        
    console.log('Successfully resized ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
        ' and uploaded to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey); 
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

3. I added a role to lambda with the following policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        }
    ]
}
```

4. I made my source bucket public so that i can easily access it but i added a policy in my destination bucket as follow

```
{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::272222288325:role/LambdaRole" //Role i assigned to my lambda function
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::safarni/*"
        }
```

**Error**:
For some reason it isn't invoking and i can't find out why so I would really appreciate any help

**Edit**
Lambda settings
[image]

My role policy
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the CloudWatch logs for your Lambda?

Comment: yes but I think it didnt even get invoked for some reason idk

Comment: I tried uploading a file to posts/12134 directory (my prefix is posts/*/) but the function wasn't invoked

Comment: Have you set a trigger for lambda? I am trying to understand how is your lambda getting invoked!

Comment: @AbdelrahmanShahda I don't see any mentions of setting a trigger from s3 to Lambda in your question. Can u confirm if u have set a trigger ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have used a prefix of `myfile/*/` this won't get invoked. You should have the prefix as `myfile/` and not `myfile/*`.

This will of course also trigger for any files that exist in the `myfile` prefix, but it is also recursive so any object with keys that start with `myfile` will also be included such as:

- `myfile/test.txt`
- `myfile/test/test.txt`
- `myfile/test/test2/test2.txt`

An S3 object name is its key, the `/` character just displays as if the structure of the S3 bucket contains a nested subfolder structure but in fact it is just [listing objects](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects-v2.html) by prefix.

Comment: Unfortunately this didnt work. I dont know if this may help or not but i tried uploading the file manully and with pre-signed url nothing still happened

Comment: I could take a screeshot for the invoke prefix and other settings if this might help

Comment: Sure upload a screenshot of your settings

Comment: What is the key of your S3 object?

Comment: okay i added some screenshots don't know if this is enough but if u needed any other screenshot just let me know

Comment: path to the file: posts/1231 (for example)     while the filename is test.jpg

Comment: How does the S3 function policy look?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218066/discussion-between-chris-williams-and-abdelrahman-shahda).

Answer (score 1):

you need to provide invoke permissions to your bucket like so:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowS3ToABCFunction",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:<region>:<account>:function:<function_name>"
    }
   ]
}
```

checkout this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Authorizing.IAM.LambdaCreatePolicy.html) for more details.

Also, in your question, I didn't see any steps to setup a trigger from s3 to lambda.
you may wanna follow this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/aws_lambda/aws_lambda_using_lambda_function_with_amazon_s3.htm) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but my first guess is that you might be missing a lambda invocation action in your statement? Something like this:

```
"Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeFunction"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
```